# Red Hat Licensing Model, a license is needed to run it?

Tags: redhat, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I've inherited two Red Hat servers at work. I'm planning on moving them to CentOS to avoid licensing costs. Now, the licenses expired on october and I've received a Red Hat phone call to renew these licenses. They tell me *this has to be solved*. I don't know if take that as an threat of some kind.

Can Red Hat force me to buy new licenses? Can I still run Red Hat without the renewed licenses?

I know that now I can't update them, but they're very isolated from the Internet and other network computers, and I'm planning on move to CentOS anyway. So that's not to worry about. I'm worrying just about legal issues.

Comment: We don't handle licensing questions here because the legality varies from location to location and we're not lawyers. That said, I'd probably ignore them if I were in your situation and were migrating away.

Comment: Thank you. Is there other, more suitable, StackExchange place to ask these licensing issues?

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis  Not really, no.  Just the nature of life that free licensing/legal advice on the internet is a minefield.

Comment: [Might want to read through the RedHat license agreement before doing anything, though - as you can see, it varies from country to country.](http://www.redhat.com/licenses/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will still run fine. You just won't be able to get official updates from the redhat network anymore. Sounds like the sales guy is trying to strong arm you into a sale.